# windows RDP send data from server to client?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I want to write a application that can send files from server to client:

1. using windows Remote Desktop login the server from the client.
2. the application on the server could reversely connect to the client and send several files to the client using the same port as the Remote Desktop.
3. A application on the client can receive the files.

can't find any solution to do that kind thing. Any idea??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using [Remote Desktop virtual channels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383509%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). See [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2007/09/20/dynamic-virtual-channels.aspx) for a sample virtual channel application.

Comment: thank you very much. I have already found it and make a simple sample work! Who want the sample could send me email for it. wangyi724@gmail.com